# svelte : the on:click event fetch the API but doesn't render

Tags: svelte

I am learning svelte and love it so far, but I have an issue when fetching an api.

The results don't display on the page and I don't really get the reason why. When the button get clicked, i console.log the data which are ok. So the problem doesn't come from the input neither from the button... it just doesn't display the results on the  tag as it should.
I am a bit lost here so thank you for your help ! Very appreciated :-)

```
<script>
    let nameOfTvshow = 'The Queen\'s Gambit'

    let searchForTvshow = getTvShow()

    async function getTvShow() {
        const res = await fetch(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${nameOfTvshow}`)
        const data = await res.json()
        console.log(data)
        return data
    }
</script>

<div>
    <input type="search" name="tvshows" bind:value={nameOfTvshow} placeholder="Search for a tvshow...">
    <button on:click={getTvShow}>Search</button>
</div>

<section>
    {#await searchForTvshow}
        <p>...Looking for the show related to {nameOfTvshow}</p>
    {:then tvshows}
        <ul>
        {#each tvshows as tvshow}
            <div>
                <li><a href={tvshow.show.url}>{tvshow.show.name}</a></li>
                <div>
                    {#each tvshow.show.genres as genre}
                    <p>{ genre }</p>
                    {/each}
                </div>
                <p>&rarr;</span>{ @html tvshow.show.summary }</p>               
            </div>
        {/each}
        </ul>
    {:catch error}
        <p>It looks like something went wrong : <span>{error}</span></p>
    {/await}
</section>
```

Comment: Can you add the response and the current output you are getting now

Comment: I think so problem is in the variable then tvshows try changing it

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `getTvShow` but its return value is not assigned to any variable. In order for your content to rerender, you need to assign that return value (a promise) to `searchForTvshow` again :

```js
<button on:click={() => searchForTvshow = getTvShow()}>Search</button>
```